# Bootstrap Make iPhone scaling the same as iPad.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My site collapses nicely for the iPad version but once it collapses for iPhone it is a mess. I would prefer just to keep the iPad version for iPhone as well.

I know I have to override `/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }`

but do I have to override each individual param? Can't I simply tell it somehow "don't collapse below 768px"

I am using a CDN hosted bootstrap and doing custom overrides in my css.

Comment: dnt customize the CDN hosted bootstrap files, try i implement your custom code, apply media queries and set the layout in css...

Answer (score 0):

This are the suggested medias:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

As you can see, here I'm using `device-width` instead of `width`.

If what you want is to use same style in iPad and iPhone and there are not constrains between 480px y 768px, you can simply:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Hope this helps!